# SPFarm.Local is return null

Tags: c#, sharepoint, null

**SPFarm.Local is return null**

I have googled.

1. x64 and x86 problem - No
2. Access issue - No

Additional
1. Database server is up
2. Sites are opening
3. CA is opening

The account is 'System Account' under which the code is running. Always worked before. Now suddenly it started returning null.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it elevated ? Is it x86 or x64 app ?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this one - I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: Scratch that - read your comment below and server restart did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple server/machine restart solved the problem. Some of my friends faced similar issue and restarting solved the issue. :)

Comment: You are my hero! (SP2013)

Answer (score 2):

I tried by changing from x64 or x86 to Any CPU in my VS2012 project but it didn't help. Finally i opened VS in administrator mode and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.local%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> SPFarm.Local = null. 
>   SPFarm.Local wants to create a connection to the
>   configuration database. In order to do so, you'll need to have
>   permissions on the configuration database. Usually the service account
>   and the application pool accounts can read the configuration database.
>   If you don't have the right to read the configuration database,
>   SPFarm.Local will be null!

Comment: Renuiz I have no access issue. Same winapp worked fine and then just stopped working because SPFarm.Local started returning null. DB was up. I was able to open sites in web browser. Do not know whats the issue. Though a simple server restart solved the issue. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 this can happen if you use Microsoft.SharePoint assemblies from 2010 version in SharePoint 2013. Simple convert your project to use 4.5 framework and you are good to go.