# Sharepoint 2013: SPFarm.Local is null when logged with other than the Administrator

Tags: security, permissions, null, sharepoint-2013

I have created a simple console project with the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            var farm = SPFarm.Local;

            Console.WriteLine(SPFarm.Local);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The SP2013 Server is installed in a virtual server from [Cloudshare](http://www.cloudshare.com/). There is another vm for the SQL Server 2012 and another one for the Active Directory 2012 (domain is AD2012.loc).

When I open the project using the `AD2012.loc/Administrator` account, it works perfect. But when I open it using my account (which is in `AD2012.loc` and in the Administrators group) `SPFarm.local` is `null`.

I know is a permission thing but since I have to rely on this `SPFarm.Local` object to use in another project, that will be executed in several servers where I don't have access to and I can't be sure they will executed as the Administrator, is there anything I can do to maybe impersonate the code to run as the SPFarm admin or something?. I have tried runned with the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` with no luck.

**UPDATE**

I've tried running the above code impersonating the SPAdmin user but still getting null.

I can't just give access to the user because this will run in client machines, and I can't tell them to give access to the SPConfig db. So I need a way to do it in the code, impersonating or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about this will work or not

i will give you two links hopw any one will work for you.

[SPFarm.Local is return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105512/spfarm-local-is-return-null)

OR

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ekraus/archive/2009/11/13/sp2010-spfarm-local-is-null-or-web-application-could-not-be-found.aspx